# Collection Sort Order in Text Field - Same values are ordered randomly

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sorting

I am sorting a custom collection by a text field EAV attribute (UMC was originally used to scaffold the module which has been heavily modified since).

`$myCollection->setOrder('my_name', 'ASC')`

`my_name` in this case often has the same value for many entries. Consider a collection of dogs. Many entries would have `labrador` as a value for `breed` field. There are many possible fields so keeping them enumerated in a `<select>` list would be cumbersome, I'd rather keep them as a text field (with my own validation so that `labrador` isn't mistaken as `labredor` or something).

The problem is that my returned results will randomly order the `my_name` field so that any entries with the same value will be clustered together but will be listed in a different order every time. **How can I make sure this ordered collection is the same each time?**

Comment: Just to add a note: I am able to work around the issue by also sorting by an additional unique field that is related to the other field but insufficient to sort by alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, why not sort by both, breed and that second (or any other) attribute? :)

i.e.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('breed','other_field');

$products->getSelect()
    ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('e.breed asc, e.other_field desc'));

foreach($products as $product) {
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

This will build a query similar to

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`breed`, `e`.`other_field` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` WHERE (e.status = 1) ORDER BY `e`.`breed` asc, `e`.`other_field` asc
```

which sorts first by `breed` and then by `other_field`.

Comment: Yes, in my case I realized I could sort by an additional field, but that may not necessarily be the case.

Comment: @pspahn you can always additionally sort by id/entity_id in case you don't have other attributes available. This way your sorting should stay the same anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. In my specific case it is just a touch cleaner to sort by my other field, but sorting by ID seems like a good work around for most cases.